# How to solve this quadratic differential equation to derive velocity in free fall?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

How do you solve this non-homogenous differential equation? $$\frac{dv}{dt} = mg - kv^2$$

Edit:

I tried to solve it by finding the particular solution:
$$v=A \implies \frac{dv}{dt}=0;$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dv}{dt} + kv^2 = mg &\implies 0 + kA^2 = mg \\
&\implies A = \sqrt{\frac{mg}{k}}.
\end{align}

Then getting the general solution for its homogenous counterpart by separating variables:

\begin{align}
\frac{dv}{dt} + kv^2 = 0 &\implies -\frac{dv}{kv^2} = dt \\
&\implies \frac{1}{kv} = t + C \\
&\implies v = \frac{1}{kt+C}.
\end{align}

The solution I got the particular solution plus the general solution:

$$v = \sqrt{\frac{mg}{k}} + \frac{1}{kt + C}.$$

Comment: You can solve by separating the variables.  $ \dfrac{dv}{m g - k v^2} = dt $

Comment: It would be nice to see your efforts - what have you tried so far to solve the equation. This would help to provide you with relevant tips and ideas

Comment: Thanks for the edit. From a common sense perspective, ignoring all the actual math except for the final answer, something seems wrong: as time goes on the falling object now gets slower and slower while in reality it gets faster and faster.

Comment: This is a non-linear equation. Solving the modified equation does not help anything. Solve $v'=k(A^2-v^2)$ via separation or as Riccati equation with a known solution. Or consider $u(t)=e^{kx(t)}$ so that $u'=kve^{kx}$, $u''=k(v'+kv^2)e^{kx}=(kmg)\,u$.

Comment: @Vincent I know, but looking at the limit of v it gives the correct answer for some reason.

Comment: The limit for $t \to \infty$ is $\sqrt{mg/k}$ which is the terminal velocity. But the other term contains an error because it should approach this speed from below, not from above as it does now.

Answer (score 1):

I shall present my answer using separation of variables. I will skip on some of the computations and present the concept directly.

$$ 
\begin{align}
\frac{dv}{dt} & =mg-kv^2\\
\frac{dv}{dt} & = -k\Big(v^2-\frac{mg}{k}\Big)\\
\frac{1}{v^2-\frac{mg}{k}}dv & = -k dt\\
\int\frac{1}{v^2- \big( \sqrt \frac{mg}{k} \big)^2}dv & = \int -k dt\\
\end{align}
$$
For simplicity we can set $\alpha= \sqrt {mg/k}$. We can apply partial fraction decomposition on the LHS of the equation.
$$
\begin{align} 
\frac{1}{v^2- \alpha^2} & = \frac{A}{v- \alpha} + \frac{B}{v + \alpha} \\
\\
\end{align}
$$
You can solve the coefficients on your own.

Solving the equation, you will arrive the answer in the form:
$$ v(t) = \frac{\alpha(1+Ce^{-2 \alpha kt})}{1-Ce^{-2 \alpha kt}}$$
for $C$ is a constant.

Now we check the system at steady-state. As we take $t \to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to \infty}v(t) & = \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\alpha(1+Ce^{-2 \alpha kt})}{1-Ce^{-2 \alpha kt}} \\
& = \alpha \\
& = \sqrt \frac{mg}{k} \\
\end{align}
$$
which is your terminal velocity.

Hope it helps.